# R:approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff) : need at least two non-NA values to interpolate

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I use the `onls` model package to calculate the orthogonal regression, use `confit(model)` to calculate the confidence interval of the equation coefficients, the sample size is 50. But it prompts an error:

```
Error in approx(sp$y, sp$x, xout = cutoff): need at least two non-NA
values to interpolate.
```

I checked and there is no same x as the previous answer to this question, so what could be the reason? Or what else can I use to solve the confidence interval?

```
# Data
x<-c(52.37,52.91,53.15,55.18,55.25,56.95,57.17,57.86,60.93,63.55,65.25,65.73,68.39,70.39,70.65,72.19,73.33,75.98,76.88,79.58,79.83,80.57,82.68,83.75,87.48,98.35,101.86,103.69,104.42,104.69,106.84,107.01,108.61,109.97,111.32,112.89,113.81,115.97,119.46,120.24,120.40,145.92,145.90,153.39,167.93,171.33,172.33,195.90,209.02,226.68,244.34,291.43,328.42,360.37,457.47,576.96,749.65)
y<-c(218500,238600,395300,144900,526900,305100,229000,291600,327800,149200,239200,1500600,150400,222500,470800,347600,356400,375400,325100,151400,395800,367900,597000,391500,479700,349900,445200,521400,505400,573700,529700,317400,379700,829500,514900,706500,877400,500800,633800,529900,738800,917300,853700,734200,587700,991900,1324300,767200,1254300,902900,966300,2615300,1183600,1842500,2455700,4384800,5117400)

# Code
DAT <- data.frame(x, y)
model1 <-onls(y ~ a * x ^ b, data = DAT, start = list(a = 1,b = 1))
confint(model1, level = 0.95)
```

Comment: Can you post minimal code and data reproducing the error? If the data set is too big, please post the output of `dput(head(sp, 20))`.

Comment: @ Rui Barradas，thank you for your reply.The original data and code I have given below：

Comment: Could it be because the model failed? I got `FAILED: Only 40 out of 57 fitted points are orthogonal.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points are not orthogonal, so fit `model1` like in the question, check orthogonality and refit (`model2`) with the orthogonal points only.

```r
library(onls)
#> Loading required package: minpack.lm

# Data
x<-c(52.37,52.91,53.15,55.18,55.25,56.95,57.17,57.86,60.93,63.55,65.25,65.73,68.39,70.39,70.65,72.19,73.33,75.98,76.88,79.58,79.83,80.57,82.68,83.75,87.48,98.35,101.86,103.69,104.42,104.69,106.84,107.01,108.61,109.97,111.32,112.89,113.81,115.97,119.46,120.24,120.40,145.92,145.90,153.39,167.93,171.33,172.33,195.90,209.02,226.68,244.34,291.43,328.42,360.37,457.47,576.96,749.65)
y<-c(218500,238600,395300,144900,526900,305100,229000,291600,327800,149200,239200,1500600,150400,222500,470800,347600,356400,375400,325100,151400,395800,367900,597000,391500,479700,349900,445200,521400,505400,573700,529700,317400,379700,829500,514900,706500,877400,500800,633800,529900,738800,917300,853700,734200,587700,991900,1324300,767200,1254300,902900,966300,2615300,1183600,1842500,2455700,4384800,5117400)

# Code
DAT <- data.frame(x, y)

# 1st fit: with the full data set DAT
model1 <- onls(y ~ a * x ^ b, data = DAT, start = list(a = 1,b = 1))
#> Obtaining starting parameters from ordinary NLS...
#>   Passed...
#>  Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'. 
#> Optimizing orthogonal NLS...
#>   Passed... Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'.
o <- check_o(model1)$Ortho
```

[image]

```r
# 2nd fit: with the orthogonal points only
model2 <- onls(y ~ a * x ^ b, data = DAT[o,], start = list(a = 1,b = 1))
#> Obtaining starting parameters from ordinary NLS...
#>   Passed...
#>  Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'. 
#> Optimizing orthogonal NLS...
#>   Passed... Relative error in the sum of squares is at most `ftol'.
confint(model2, level = 0.95)
#> Waiting for profiling to be done...
#>          2.5%       97.5%
#> a 2378.957049 4012.371390
#> b    1.079456    1.180696
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is worth considering whether this sample can be deleted In this study, the number of samples is small, and the coefficients of the fitting equation (A and B are self-defined), that is, the samples to be deleted change when the initial value is changed.